# Unable to recreate multiselect with updated params, destroy does not allow recreate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am using the bootstrap multiselect from https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect.

Problem Scenario: Based on the users input, I am receiving the options to be included through an ajax call. 
I want to include the select all and filter only when there are more than 1 option. I am trying to add the select all and filter properties dynamically. But the problem is, the multiselect seems to remember the properties I set in the previous call.

When the page is loaded, the ajax call returns 3 options, the select all and filter are enabled for the multiselect. But when the user changes input, the ajax call now returns only 1 option. I am updating the function params as in (a) and trying to recreate the multiselect as in (b)

```
           (a) function updateParams(options, params){
                   if (options.length<1 ){
                       params.includeSelectAllOption = false;
                       params.enableFiltering = false;
                       params.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering = false;
                   } else {
                       params.includeSelectAllOption = true;
                       params.enableFiltering = true;
                       params.enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering = true;
                   }
                   return params;
               }


              (b) {.... 
                   // $(ele).multiselect('destroy');
                   $(ele).html('');
                   var params = $.extend(true, {}, paramsGiven);
                   params = updateParams(options, params);
                   $(ele).multiselect(params);
                   $(ele).multiselect("rebuild");
                   ...}
```

I copied the params so that they donot persist between user inputs. I printed the params and paramsGiven before and after updating and they carry the properties as I expected. The above code does not seem to recreate the multiselect with new params. I also tried destroying and recreating but it just destroys and does not recreate.

Could anyone please help me understand whats going wrong here?